# Areas of code not functioning?

Tags: python, if-statement, printing, while-loop, passwords

The code:

```
#Welcome the user to the application.
print("Hello, please enter a password with a minimum of six characters and a max of twelve.");

#Set a variable called MinPass and set a value of 6.
MinPass = 6;

#Set a variable called MaxPass and set a value of 12.
MaxPass = 12;

#Set variable EnteredPass and wait for user input
EnteredPass = input("Password: ");

while len(EnteredPass) < MinPass:
    print("Your password is too short, please enter a longer password and try again")
    EnteredPass = input("Password: ");

while len(EnteredPass) > MaxPass:
    print("Your password is too long, please shorten it and try again!");
    EnteredPass = input("Password: ");
else:
  print("Accepted!")

  while EnteredPass.isdigit:
    print("Needs letters");
    EnteredPass = input("Password: ");

if EnteredPass.isalpha:
  print("Needs numbers")
  EnteredPass = input("Password: ")
```

The issue:

When I run the program and enter something 'incorrectly', it always runs the same function, and I don't know why!

Comment: This is not C++, you do not need to terminate lines with `;`

Comment: Do not limit password length, you will be hashing the password so you don't need to limit this.

Comment: stuart     ---I have to, it's for coursework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually *call* your function

```
if EnteredPass.isalpha():
```

Instead of

```
if EnteredPass.isalpha:
```

The latter just implicitly converts the *function object* to `bool` which will always result in `True`

Comment: Same with `.isdigit`.